# Fetch value from delimited string using Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have an analytics tool which allows me to take Regex and pull out specific parts of a string using Regular Expressions. In my example below, I'm looking to pull out the values which are in the third slot using the delimiter ":" and I can use the `$` to reference a value to return.

**Example Keys**
     mfast_acquired_theresasale
     alp:psch_nb_b2b:thisisthekeyword:thisistheoccassion
     alp:psch_nb:paid keyword:rewardsclub
     alp:psch_nb:gifts:sale
     alp:psch_things:keyword_phrase

**Expected Result** 
     (no match expected)
     thisisthekeyword
     paid keyword
     gifts
     keyword_phrase

**What I've reasonably tried so far:** 
This failed --> `^alp:([^:]+)$`

This failed --> `^alp.*:([^:]+)$`

and then I referenced $1  to return what was matched

**Results Returned with what I've tried:**
No matches have been returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use

```
^alp:[^:]+:([^:]+)
     ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT1mE7/2)

**Details:**

- `^` - start of string
- `alp:` - a literal `alp:`
- `[^:]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `([^:]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more non-`:`s

If GA expects a full string match, use [`^alp:[^:]+:([^:]+).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/kT1mE7/1).

Comment: Am not allowed to vote publicly yet but I did upvote already and just marked it as accepted, thank you!